# Add a point to seaborn stripplot that signifies mean for each category

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, seaborn

I am using seaborn to create a stripplot for three conditions. The example data look like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
         'bill': [50, 45, 33, 23, 22, 34, 54, 22, 54, 76], 
         'day': ['sat', 'sat', 'sat', 'sat', 'sat', 'sun', 'sun', 'sun', 'sun', 'sun'], 
         'tip': ['yes', 'no', 'yes', 'no', 'yes', 'no', 'yes', 'no', 'yes', 'no']
         }
         )
```

The seaborn plot:

```
sns.stripplot(x='day', y='bill', data=df, jitter=True, hue='tip', palette='deep', dodge=True)
```

How can I plot a point in each category that signifies the mean of that category?

I have tried adapting this [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67481900/how-to-add-a-mean-line-to-a-seaborn-stripplot-or-swarmplot#:%7E:text=import%20seaborn%20as,p) , but this created average for day but not separate averages for day/tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe overlay a [`pointplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.pointplot.html#seaborn.pointplot)?

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.stripplot(x='day', y='bill', data=df, jitter=True, hue='tip', palette='deep', dodge=True)
sns.pointplot(x='day', y='bill', data=df, hue='tip', palette='deep', dodge=True, linestyles='', errorbar=None)
```

Output:

[image]

You can cheat a bit to have a more meaningful legend:

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.stripplot(x='day', y='bill', data=df, jitter=True, hue='tip', palette='deep', dodge=True)
sns.pointplot(x='day', y='bill', data=df.assign(tip=df['tip']+' (avg)'),
              hue='tip', palette='deep',
              dodge=True, linestyles='', errorbar=None)
```

[image]